# $resource object empty after get request

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, ngresource

I want to save JSON-Data from my Rest-API in a $scope variable for further usage.
The problem is when the Code is executed, i see in Firebug that i've got the JSON Data sucessfully, but the problem is, that i cant save it in my Scope variable and i dont know why.

My app.js

```
var app = angular.module('shop', ['ngRoute','ngResource'])
  .factory('Customerservice', function ($resource) {
      return $resource('http://localhost:8080/Shop/:customer',{customer: "@customer"});
})
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/name/:ID', {
          templateUrl : "Customer/customers.html",
          controller : 'customerController'
      });
})
  .controller('customerController', function ($scope,Customerservice) {
      $scope.customerinfo = Customerservice.get({customer: "Mark"});
      alert($scope.customerinfo);
});
```

Like i said, i've got the JSON-Data but the Problem is in my Controller "customerController". I just put the alert function in my Code to see whats in my $scope.customerinfo. And well the Content of customerinfo is just object: Object.
I noticed something strange while debbuging with Firebug. It looks like that the alert is executed before the get request. This would explain why there is no data in my $scope variable. Can anyone help me here.

Comment: If you try to alert object, alert would show only [object: objcet]. To see the value in alert, you have stringify the json object by using JSON.stringify function. Or for viewing it, you can use console.log().

Comment: use console log instead of alert

Comment: Do one thing put debugger at alert and open Chrome Developer Tool, when execution stop at that line, just hover on $scope.customerinfo. You will see the content of object .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use $promise property

It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

```
$scope.customerinfo = CustomerService.get({customer: "Mark"});

console.log($scope.customerinfo); //Empty object
```

However, the `$resource` service also attaches a `$promise` property that can be used to delay code execution until the data has arrived from the server:

```
$scope.customerinfo = CustomerService.get({customer: "Mark"});
console.log($scope.customerinfo); //Empty object

//USE $promise
$scope.customerinfo.$promise
  .then(function(info) {
    console.log($scope.customerinfo); //Fulfilled object
    return info;
}).catch(function(errorResponse) {
    console.log(errorResponse.status);
    throw errorResponse;
});
```

> The Resource instances and collections have these additional properties:
>
> - `$promise`: the [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) of the original server interaction that created this instance or collection.
>
> On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or collection object, updated with data from server. This makes it easy to use in [resolve section of $routeProvider.when()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) to defer view rendering until the resource(s) are loaded.
>
> On failure, the promise is rejected with the [http response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) object, without the `resource` property.
>
> [— AngularJS ngResource $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: ty this solved the problem for me. I was exactly looking for something like $promise

Comment: You are welcome. I am sorry others rushed to downvote your question.

Answer (score 1):

`$resource` is async api so you can't get value from direct return of function call, its contains a variable `$promise` which will return `promise` so you need to call `then` function of it

Try this

```
UserService.get({customer: "Mark"}).$promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.customerinfo = data;
    alert($scope.customerinfo);
});
```

Comment: `$resource` object methods don't return promises. There is no `.then` method on objects returned by $resource factory. *It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.* See [AngularJS $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Comment: Yes, you are right `$resource` object methods don't return promises but it contains `$promise` variable which return the promise, I've updated my code according to this

Comment: ty your answer and georgeawg helped me solve the problem